# How can I make presto (or anything) an executable file on a Linux Server?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I tried CHMOD along with the file directory but it just can't seem to find it for some reason.

I've tried the following:

```
-bash: homeec2-user: command not found
[ec2-user@_________ ~]$ chmod u+x ./home/ec2-user/presto.jar
chmod: cannot access ‘./home/ec2-user/presto.jar’: No such file or directory
[ec2-user@_________ ~]$ chmod u+x ./home/ec2-user/presto
chmod: cannot access ‘./home/ec2-user/presto’: No such file or directory
[ec2-user@_________ ~]$ chmod u+x ./home/ec2-user/
chmod: cannot access ‘./home/ec2-user/’: No such file or directory
[ec2-user@_________ ~]$ chmod u+x ~/home/ec2-user/
chmod: cannot access ‘/home/ec2-user/home/ec2-user/’: No such file or directory
[ec2-user@_________ ~]$ chmod u+x ~./home/ec2-user/
chmod: cannot access ‘~./home/ec2-user/’: No such file or directory
[ec2-user@_________ ~]$ ./presto --server localhost:8080 --catalog hive --schema default#
-bash: ./presto: No such file or directory
[ec2-user@_________ ~]$ home/
-bash: home/: No such file or directory
```

This is the correct directory I'm trying to link to as well. Am I doing something wrong?
For reference, I'm on this point in a tutorial (so you know what I'm trying to do)
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/cli.html

Comment: What's in your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files? That first line looks worrying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leading `.` looks like the culprit:

```
[ec2-user@_________ ~]$ chmod u+x ./home/ec2-user/presto.jar
chmod: cannot access ‘./home/ec2-user/presto.jar’: No such file or directory
```

should be one of:

```
$ chmod u+x presto.jar
$ chmod u+x ./presto.jar
$ chmod u+x ~/presto.jar
```

EDIT: To expand - commands assume the file you're operating on are in the current directory (the first example). A `.` explicitly means 'this directory' (example 2), and the `~` expands to your home directory: `/home/ec2-user` in this case (example 3).

Comment: Hey thanks, that may have worked but I'm not sure. I'm now stuck on the next part where i'm trying to run it with ./presto --server localhost:8080 --catalog hive --schema default. but am still getting "No such file or directory". Any ideas? I marked your answer as correct anyway because it did answer the first issue

Comment: According to the link you posted, you need to rename the file from `presto.jar` to `presto`.

Comment: Hey, thanks you solved my issue. For future reference, any idea why I was downvoted so heavily?

Comment: Probably because of a general lack of knowledge about linux on what is primarily a site for business/enterprise sysadmins.

Comment: ah yes, we literally are only setting up linux servers now and I've never done it before being a graduate so It's all very new to me. Thanks for your help regardless.